# Makefile always rebuilding

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using the following simple Makefile to build some simple files. I am really new to making Makefile. I don't know why it keeps in rebuilding even though the files are built after first make and I am not editing any of the file.

```
EXE    = nextgenrsm
CC     = gcc
LIBS   = StarterWare_Files/
CFLAGS = -c 

INCLUDE_PATH =  StarterWare_Files/

MAIN_SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
MAIN_OBS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(MAIN_SRC))

LIB_SRC = $(wildcard StarterWare_Files/*.c)
LIB_OBS = $(patsubst StarterWare_Files/%.c,%.o,$(LIB_SRC))

output: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS)
    $(CC) $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIBS)$(LIB_OBS) -o $(EXE) 

$(MAIN_OBS): $(MAIN_SRC) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) *.c -I$(INCLUDE_PATH)

$(LIB_OBS): $(LIB_SRC) 
    cd $(LIBS); \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) *.c -I../

clean:
    rm -rf $(LIBS)*.o $(EXE) *.o
```

**NEW EDITED MAKEFILE**

```
EXE    = nextgenrsm
CC     = gcc
LIBS   = StarterWare_Files/
CPPFLAGS = _IStarterWare_Files/


MAIN_OBS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
LIB_OBS  = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard StarterWare_Files/*.c))

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS)
   $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c 
   $(CC) -o $@ -MD -MP $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

ALL_DEPS = $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(MAIN_OBS), $(LIB_OBS))
-include $(ALL_DEPS)

clean:
   rm -f $(LIB_OBS) $(EXE) $(MAIN_OBS) $(ALL_DEPS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Whenever I do touch StarterWare_Files/example.h and try to do make again it throws me error that gcc cannot specify -o with -c or -S with Multiple files. Basically the command becomes something like this gcc -o main.o -IStarterWare_Files -c main.c StarterWare_Files/test.h StarterWare_Files/add.h..

Comment: Is make rebuilding `$(MAIN_OBS)`? `$(LIB_OBS)`? `$(EXE)`? All of them? Run `make -d` and look through the output and it will tell you what it thinks needs to be rebuilt and why. Also your makefile isn't correct. It tells make that every `.o` file has *every* `.c` file as a prerequisite not just its matching one. So changing *any* `.c` file is going to recompile *every* `.o` file in that set.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes it is building all of them. How to make that change? that it only refers to it's own C file.

Comment: It probably is only building the `$(LIB_OBS)` files again. That's because you remove the directory prefix from the `.c` file when you set the value of `$(LIB_OBS)` but you then have the target make the `.o` files in the directory so make can't match those up (because `foo.o` isn't the same as `StarterWare_Files/foo.o`).

Comment: @EtanReisner what is the significance of $^?

Comment: That's one of the make [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: @EtanReisner I am getting an error with Maxim Egorushkin automatic dependency generation. If i touch any of the .h files in StarterWare_Files/.. that gcc cannot specify -o with -c or -S with Multiple files. I need to do make clean and then make again or it wont work

Comment: I'd  have to see the new makefile to be able to really comment on that. I don't see how that error could come from the gcc command listed in his answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have added the new one for your reference

Comment: I saw. I saw the new question you filed too. I commented on the answer here with the solution to the problem that Jonathan Wakely and I found.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks a lot Etan Reisner, Maxim Egorushkin and Jonathan Wakely. I would be really glad to work and get to learn under you guys. I know my questions seem silly but I am trying to learn and rather than being stuck, I would prefer to ask.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your default target is `output` but your makefile never produces such a file, so that every time you invoke `make` it tries to build `output` file.

The solution is to mark `output` target as a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets). As well as `clean` target:

```
.PHONY: output clean
```

---

You can take advantage of [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) that compile `.o` from `.c` and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to reduce your makefile to:

```
EXE    := nextgenrsm
CC     := gcc
LIBS   := StarterWare_Files/
CPPFLAGS := -IStarterWare_Files

MAIN_OBS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
LIB_OBS  := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard StarterWare_Files/*.c))

all: $(EXE)
$(EXE) : $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS) $(EXE)

.PHONY: all clean
```

And if you would like automatic header dependency generation add:

```
# This rule produces .o and also .d (-MD -MP) from .c.
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -MD -MP $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

# This includes all .d files produced along when building .o.
# On the first build there are not going to be any .d files.
# Hence, ignore include errors with -.
ALL_DEPS := $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS))
-include $(ALL_DEPS)

clean:
    rm -f $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS) $(EXE) $(ALL_DEPS)
```

Comment: While true this wouldn't cause it to recompile anything assuming the other targets create their target files correctly (which they appear to do). Oh, no the `$(LIB_OBS)` ones don't have the directory in the name.

Comment: You should probably explain the change you made to the value of `$(LIB_OBS)` a bit (and how it solves the problem).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It is still behaving the same

Comment: @Aakash Post the output of `find . -type f -name "*.c"`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It works now and it doesn't compile again. Sorry if it sounds stupid since I am just a beginner but what is  ALL_DEPS := $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS))
-include $(ALL_DEPS)    ....... this part doing

Comment: If I do this it is giving me compilation Errors that main.c wasn't able to refer to a function which was declared in one of the .c files in StarterWare_Files/ directory

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It doesn't compile the executable with one of the dependent .o files which is in StarterWare_Files/ directory.................. It should be gcc -o nextgenrsm main.o StarterWare_Files/test.o ..... instead it shows gcc -o nextgenrsm main.o... only

Comment: `$<` (first prerequisite) is a typo in the `$(EXE) : $(MAIN_OBS) $(LIB_OBS)` recipe. It should be `$^` (all prerequisites). I just edited to fix it.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are right, I often confuse `$<` with `$^`.

Comment: Yeah, I have to look that up myself fairly routinely. BSD make uses named variables to avoid this confusion I believe.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I am not able to get you what you meant by ALL_DEPS and the line after that .. If i don't include both of those lines it still works.

Comment: @Aakash Added a comment for you. I learned GNU Make just by reading the entire manual. It is a bit long, but nothing less would do, nothing more is required.

Comment: @Aakash If you remove those two lines, that will still compile, and recompile if you change any of `.c`. But it will not recompile if you change any of the header files included by your `.c` files.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It throws me error If i touch any of the .h files in StarterWare_Files/.. that  gcc cannot specify -o with -c or -S with Multiple files. I need to do make clean and then make again or it wont work

Comment: The `$^` in the `%.o` target is incorrect. It needs to be `$<`.

Comment: @EtanReisner, my mnemonic for `$<` is that it's a left-arrow, where the first prerequisite is the "leftmost" one. So visually I read it as "that one over there, all the way to the left" :) And `$^` is "all those files up there, above me". It works well enough to jog my memory ... but doesn't help for the other special variables.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

```
$(MAIN_OBS): $(MAIN_SRC)
```

You have declared that every object file dependent on every source file. Likewise for the library ones.  The above rule expands to:

```
foo.o bar.o xyzzy.o .... : foo.c bar.c xyzzy.c ...
```

Therefore, if a time-stamp changes on any source file, every object file will be rebuilt.

What you have to do is have individual dependencies:

```
# foo.o depends only on foo.c, not on bar.c
foo.o: foo.c

# bar.o depends only on bar.c, not on foo.c
bar.o: bar.c
```

and so on.  Usually, this is not done. Rather, we use GNU Make's pattern rules to write one common rule:

```
%.o: %c
        # build commands to make .o from .c
```

There is already a built-in rule for this which is often sufficient, and can be customized it by altering variables like `CC` and `CFLAGS`.

Thanks to built-in rules, simple makefiles usually only have to declare the dependency between the executable object and the object files. Make will automatically deduce the prerequisite from an object file by trying various possibilities. When asked to evaluate `foo.o`, it will automatically discover that there exists a `foo.c` file, which must be `foo.o`'s prerequisite.  Then if `foo.o` is older than `foo.c` or does not exist, Make will search its database of rules and discover that this combination matches the `%.o: %.c` pattern rule, and it will run its recipe body to update `foo.o`.

You should use the `:=` style immediate variable assignment rather than the delayed `=` assignment. Because you have `$(wildcard ...)` in the right hand side of an `=` assignment, every time the variable is substituted, the `$(wildcard ...)` syntax is evaluated, and the file system is traversed to find files.

Do not use `$(wildcard ...)` in the first place to gather the source files. Unless you work in a meticulously clean way, this will pull in unwanted files, like some random `test.c` that you happen to create, and so `test.o` gets linked to your program (perhaps successfully). It doesn't take much effort to explicitly list all the object files:

```
OBJS := foo.o bar.o ...
```

for objects in a subdirectory, you can use `$(addprefix ...)` to shorten it:

```
OBJS := foo.o bar.o ... $(addprefix subdir/,stack.o parser.o ...)
```

Comment: This is *a* problem but not *the* problem. *The* problem is the `LIB_OBS` variable value.